# ORA-01722 after creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, view

The view is generated using :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW USER_AUD_VIEW (AUDIT_ID, USER_ID, TABLE_NAME_TXT, COLUMN_NAME_TXT, OLD_VALUE_TXT, NEW_VALUE_TXT, AUDIT_LAST_UPDATED_DT, AUDIT_UPDATED_USER_ID, EVALUATOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
AS
SELECT acm.audit_id,
CAST(GET_TOKEN(GET_TOKEN(acm.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUES,1,','),2,':') AS VARCHAR2(64)) AS user_id,
acm.table_name_txt,
CASE WHEN (acm.table_name_txt = 'XREF_USER_PRODUCT')
THEN (mstr_product.product_description_txt || '/' || acm.column_name_txt)
ELSE acm.column_name_txt
END AS column_name_txt,
CASE WHEN UPPER(acm.column_name_txt) = 'PASSWORD_TXT'
THEN '******'
ELSE acm.old_value_txt
END AS old_value_txt,
CASE WHEN UPPER(acm.column_name_txt) = 'PASSWORD_TXT'
THEN '******'
ELSE acm.new_value_txt
END AS new_value_txt,
acm.system_dt,
CASE WHEN UPPER(acm.audit_updated_user_id) = 'UNKNOWN'
 THEN acm.audit_updated_user_id
 ELSE (users.user_id
|| ' ('
|| DECODE(users.last_name_txt, NULL,' ' , users.last_name_txt)
|| ', '
|| DECODE(users.first_name_txt, NULL,' ' , users.first_name_txt)
|| ')' )
END AS audit_updated_user_id,
acm.evaluator_id,
CASE WHEN UPPER(acm.table_name_txt) = 'XREF_USER_PRODUCT'
 THEN TO_NUMBER(trim(GET_TOKEN(GET_TOKEN(acm.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUES,2,','),2,':')))
 ELSE 0
END AS product_id
FROM audit_config_maintenance acm,
users,
mstr_product
WHERE acm.table_name_txt in ('USERS','XREF_USER_PRODUCT','XREF_USER_FUNCTION')
AND UPPER(acm.audit_updated_user_id) = UPPER(users.user_id)
AND CASE WHEN UPPER(acm.table_name_txt) = 'XREF_USER_PRODUCT'
     THEN     TO_NUMBER(trim(GET_TOKEN(GET_TOKEN(acm.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUES,2,','),2,':')))
     ELSE -1
END = mstr_product.product_id
AND acm.primary_key_values is not null
/
```

When I do a desc USER_AUD_VIEW, I get

```
Name      Null?             Type
AUDIT_ID    NOT NULL        NUMBER
USER_ID                 VARCHAR2(64)
TABLE_NAME_TXT          VARCHAR2(30)
COLUMN_NAME_TXT         VARCHAR2(81)
OLD_VALUE_TXT           VARCHAR2(64)
NEW_VALUE_TXT           VARCHAR2(64)
AUDIT_LAST_UPDATED_DT   DATE
AUDIT_UPDATED_USER_ID   VARCHAR2(71)
EVALUATOR_ID            NUMBER
PRODUCT_ID              NUMBER
```

And yet, when I do a select * from USER_AUD_VIEW, I get

ORA-01722: invalid number

Am I doing something wrong with the view creation?

Comment: Your view syntax looks fine. You're getting this error because the query underlying the view is giving this error when run. In particular -- you're calling `TO_NUMBER` in two places. Have you checked to make sure that `trim(GET_TOKEN(GET_TOKEN(acm.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUES,2,','),2,':'))` is, in fact, always a valid number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> select TO_NUMBER('1AB234') from dual;

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:

SQL> select TO_NUMBER('1234') from dual;
TO_NUMBER('1234')
-----------------
         1234
```

The view would execute the `select` in the `view`s code when you issue a `select` on the view. Its more like instead of writing the whole big `select` again, you simply run `select` on the view - This means, the `desc` on the view is fine but the data in the `select` which creates the view causes problem when you try `TO_NUMBER` conversion on a field value which is alpha numeric. `TO_NUMBER(val)` requires that `val` be only numbers (in character form), any alphabet (A-Z, a-z) or any special character within `val` will cause `ORA-01722`.

So that's a bummer, **But wait!** we can do something about it and get only the numbers from the field and ignore any alpha or special chars from it.

```
SQL> select to_number(regexp_replace('1!@#2Aa33-*^4','[^[:digit:]]')) from dual;

VAL
------
12334
```

***Caveat***- the solution above may not be so friendly for decimal numbers. But to give an overall idea.

So the `regexp`-man to your rescue would be something like below (assuming `GET_TOKEN` works well)-

```
TO_NUMBER(regexp_replace(GET_TOKEN(GET_TOKEN(acm.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUES,2,','),2,':'),'[^[:digit:]]'))
```

Comment: Thanks dude, and there are no decimal numbers, but this is much better than going through the table and removing the crap data.